# Changing value of variable based on elseif

Tags: jquery

I am new in stack, and new in jQuery. I found here some reactions, so I collect these "calculator". It´s functional, but there is one problem, the variable called "hodnota" isn´t changing the value according to the elseif statement.

Please, where is the problem, don´t know anybody? :-)

Simply I need change a value called "hodnota" based on variables values in the "if conditions" and when the select(.ninja-forms-field) is changing...

My code is here...

```
    <script>
var vyska;
var barva;
var rozmery;
var $hodnota = $(this.hash);
var pocet;

rozmery=jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_165 :selected").text();
barva=jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_167 :selected").text();
vyska=jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_166 :selected").text();


if(/200x200cm/i.test(rozmery)&&/140/i.test(vyska)&&/režná/i.test(barva)){
hodnota=2380;
}else if(/200x200cm/i.test(rozmery)&&/150/i.test(vyska)&&/režná/i.test(barva)){
$hodnota=2480;
}else if(/200x200cm/i.test(rozmery)&&/160/i.test(vyska)&&/režná/i.test(barva)){
$hodnota=2780;
}else if(/205x205cm/i.test(rozmery)&&/140/i.test(vyska)&&/režná/i.test(barva)){
$hodnota=2480;
}else if(/205x205cm/i.test(rozmery)&&/150/i.test(vyska)&&/režná/i.test(barva)){
hodnota=2580;
}else if(/205x205cm/i.test(rozmery)&&/160/i.test(vyska)&&/režná/i.test(barva)){
$hodnota=2880;
}else{
$hodnota=0;
}

jQuery('.ninja-forms-field').change(function(){
alert($hodnota);
});


</script>
```

Comment: hodnota gets set once at start-up. You'll need to add the calculation to your event handler to get it to recalculate hodnota. There must also be a better way of doing what you're trying to achieve, without repeating so many checks and hard-coding the calculation results for given inputs only?

Comment: Umm, thanks. Hodnota is price for specific type of height and width and color of tenth. Prices hasn´t any easy relationship with the properties. I do it according this table: http://typko.cz/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cenik_podsadove_stany.pdf (sorry, it´s czech language ).

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I think there's probably better ways of storing the data, e.g. a map of barva -> map of rozmery -> map of vyska -> price, or at least test barva=rezna once and then nest the next level of ifs inside that, etc.

Comment: You right, Rup.
I' ll be thinking of structure my IFs.

I change it to groups called rozmery and i check it first, but still i must found how to store the correct value.

I am only beginner, and my english is relatively poor :-D.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some fiddle how to solve the problem...
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/byz9g/1/)

```
function spocitejHodnotu() {

    var rozmer = jQuery('#ninja_forms_field_165 option:selected').text();
    var vyska = jQuery('#ninja_forms_field_166 option:selected').text();
    var barva = jQuery('#ninja_forms_field_167 option:selected').text();

    var is200 = /200x200cm/i.test(rozmer);
    var is205 = /205x205cm/i.test(rozmer);
    var is140 = /140/i.test(vyska);
    var is150 = /150/i.test(vyska);
    var is160 = /160/i.test(vyska);
    var isRezna = /režná/i.test(barva);
    var isSeda= /šedá/i.test(barva);
    var isSahara=/sahara/i.test(barva);
    var isKhaki=/khaki/i.test(barva);
    var is440=/režná 440g na m2/i.test(barva);  
    var hodnota = 0;

    if (is200) {
      if (is140) {
        if (isRezna) {
            hodnota=2380;
         } else if(isSeda){
            hodnota=2520;
        } else if(isSahara){
            hodnota=2520;
        } else if(isKhaki){
            hodnota=2600;
        } else if(is440){
            hodnota=3000;
        }
      }
      if (is150) {
        if (isRezna) {
            hodnota=2480;
         } else if(isSeda){
            hodnota=2620;
        } else if(isSahara){
            hodnota=2620;
        } else if(isKhaki){
            hodnota=2700;
        } else if(is440){
            hodnota=3100;
        }
      }
      if (is160) {
        if (isRezna) {
            hodnota=2780;
         } else if(isSeda){
            hodnota=2920;
        } else if(isSahara){
            hodnota=2920;
        } else if(isKhaki){
            hodnota=3000;
        } else if(is440){
            hodnota=3500;
        }
      }
    }
    if (is205) {
      if (is140) {
        if (isRezna) {
            hodnota=2480;
         } else if(isSeda){
            hodnota=2620;
        } else if(isSahara){
            hodnota=2620;
        } else if(isKhaki){
            hodnota=2700;
        } else if(is440){
            hodnota=3100;
        }
      }
      if (is150) {
        if (isRezna) {
            hodnota=2580;
         } else if(isSeda){
            hodnota=2720;
        } else if(isSahara){
            hodnota=2720;
        } else if(isKhaki){
            hodnota=2800;
        } else if(is440){
            hodnota=3250;
        }
      }
      if (is160) {
        if (isRezna) {
            hodnota=2880;
         } else if(isSeda){
            hodnota=3020;
        } else if(isSahara){
            hodnota=3020;
        } else if(isKhaki){
            hodnota=3100;
        } else if(is440){
            hodnota=3600;
        }
      }
    }   

    return hodnota;

}

// tohle se provede, pokud se změní nějaký select
jQuery('#ninja_forms_form_7').find('select').change(function () {
    var hodnota = spocitejHodnotu();
    alert(hodnota);
});

// tohle se provede při načtení skriptu
alert(spocitejHodnotu());
```